# Terraform authenticate azurerm with SAS token fails

Tags: terraform, azure-storage-account, azure-rm

I use the following terrform configration to store my terraform state in azure storage account container:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.5.7"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = "~>3.74.0"
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }

  # Populated by command line arguments when running terraform init
  backend "azurerm" {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  use_cli = false # Forces terraform to not use the cli for authentication
}
```

I then init and plan it like this:

```
terraform init \
    -backend-config="storage_account_name=storage" \
    -backend-config="container_name=tf-state-azure-infrastructure" \
    -backend-config="key=azure-infrastructure.tfstate" \
    -backend-config="sas_token=123"

terraform plan -out="tfplan"
```

Init is fine but plan fails with the following:

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: unable to build authorizer for Resource Manager API: no Authorizer could be configured, please check your configuration
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on providers.tf line 16, in provider "azurerm":
│   16: provider "azurerm" {
│
╵
```

Why does planning fail here? The SAS token I am testing with has all permissions on the correct container.

I have followed the official docs: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm

Upon setting the Terraform log level to DEBUG, I could se that it does get 200 OK from the container  in the storage account so it is something else that is causing this error.

```
2023-10-03T10:50:07.801+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.74.0_x5: plugin address: network=unix address=/tmp/plugin3518968587 timestamp=2023-10-03T10:50:07.801+0200
2023-10-03T10:50:07.801+0200 [DEBUG] provider: using plugin: version=5
2023-10-03T10:50:07.972+0200 [WARN]  ValidateProviderConfig from "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\"]" changed the config value, but that value is unused
2023-10-03T10:50:07.975+0200 [ERROR] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.74.0_x5: Response contains error diagnostic: @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.19.0/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:58 diagnostic_detail= diagnostic_summary="unable to build authorizer for Resource Manager API: no Authorizer could be configured, please check your configuration" tf_proto_version=5.4 tf_rpc=Configure @module=sdk.proto diagnostic_severity=ERROR tf_provider_addr=provider tf_req_id=78d2bb12-36c0-f24c-fdcf-45406c4be7e9 timestamp=2023-10-03T10:50:07.975+0200
2023-10-03T10:50:07.975+0200 [ERROR] vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\"]" error: unable to build authorizer for Resource Manager API: no Authorizer could be configured, please check your configuration
2023-10-03T10:50:07.976+0200 [INFO]  backend/local: plan operation completed
```

Comment: I have used this configuration, its working fine for me.
 provider "azurerm" {
      use_oidc            = true
      storage_use_azuread = true
      use_cli = false
      features {}
    }
Check the same issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/20794). If you are facing any issues while using `use_cli = false`, you can use `use_oidc = true`.

Comment: I have tried those settings as well. I am thinking perhaps the issue is that tf is not assuming any role and thus it cannot really create resources in azure with only a SAS token?

Comment: Yes, when using a SAS token, typically does not have the capability to assume Azure roles for resource creation and management. A SAS token provides limited access to specific Azure resources and operations, and it doesn't provide the same level of flexibility and control as Azure AD authentication or service principals.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
Error: unable to build authorizer for Resource Manager API: please check your configuration
```

Make sure that the `SAS token` you are using to upload `tfstate` file to `storage account` has the necessary permissions on the `Azure Storage container`.

I have used below terraform code and assigned following permission to `SAS Token` to upload `tfstate` file to storage account using `SAS Token`.

[image]

```json
    terraform {
      required_version = ">= 1.5.7"
    
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          version = "~>3.74.0"
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        }
      }
    
      # Populated by command line arguments when running terraform init
      backend "azurerm" {}
    }
    provider "azurerm" {
      use_oidc            = true
      storage_use_azuread = true
      use_cli = false
      features {}
    }
```

**Terraform init:**

```
  terraform init -backend-config="storage_account_name=venkatdemotest" -backend-config="container_name=venkat" -backend-config="key=azure-infrastructure.tfstate" -backend-config="sas_token=fjdndhffj"
```

**Result**

[image]

Once ran the above Terraform code  the`tfstate` file has been uploaded to `storage account` as below.

[image]

Check the same issue reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/20794).

Comment: Did you also add any resource, for example a resource group or similar? Because this does not work for me.

Comment: If you use a SAS Token for authentication, it doesn't have authorization to create any resources in Azure. It only provides access to the Storage Account. If you want to store backend files, you can use a Service Principal (SP).